# Evaluating a String in Prolog

Tags: string, prolog, evaluation

In prolog I have a string that needs to be evaluated, for example:

```
X = '4+2/5'
```

Is there a way to convert or parse this string into an expression to be evaluated?

Something like:

```
?- String_Eval('4+2/5', Result).
Result = 4.4.
```

Using SWI-Prolog 6.6.6.

Thanks

Comment: Which Prolog interpreter are you using?

Comment: SWI-Prolog 6.6.6.
I'll update the question to have this information, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the predicate [term_to_atom/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_to_atom/2) to convert the atom (what you call a string) into an evaluable term, then use the `is` operator to perform the specified operation(s).  Care should be taken if security is a concern as this roughly equivalent to an `eval` in JavaScript.

Full example

```
?- term_to_atom( T, '4 + 2 / 5' ).
T = 4+2/5.

?- term_to_atom( T, '4 + 2 / 5' ), X is T.
T = 4+2/5,
X = 4.4.
```

Comment: Wow, didn't think it would be that easy. Thank you.